# How do I get rid of these spots from my curry plant?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, diseases

How do I get rid of these spots from my curry plant?

[image: Photo of the curry plant]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a scale infestation and it's quite advanced, unfortunately. It is quite difficult to treat on edible plants, but **neem oil** spray may control it.

In theory, you should prune out severely affected branches,  but this is quite a small plant and the extent of the scale would mean removing too much growth.

Further information here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/rid-scale-curry-plant-35319.html

Comment: If you have the time, they can easily be scrapped off with a fingernail. I have done it on a small bay bush. You will need to go back later and check to see if you missed any .